# Postgres query performance is damaged when adding a simple OR clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

An app that I'm working with runs a query like this:

```
SELECT
   "categories"."id" 
FROM
   "categories" 
WHERE
(
      ('f' ) 
      OR categories.id NOT IN 
      (
         SELECT
            category_id 
         FROM
            category_groups
      )
);
```

This query takes an extremely long time to finish, and I haven't seen it finish yet. Our "categories" table has 65947 rows and our "category_groups" table has 131,780 rows.

When running "EXPLAIN" on this query, it says that this query will "cost" a ton of work (cost=1000.29..109033834.49).

I edited this query to remove that `('f') OR` section of the clause, as shown in the below query:

```
SELECT
   "categories"."id" 
FROM
   "categories" 
WHERE
(
      categories.id NOT IN 
      (
         SELECT
            category_id 
         FROM
            category_groups
      )
);
```

This query finishes very quickly, and it's "cost" when EXPLAIN-ing it is much lower (6283.94..10190.09).

Similarly, if I replace the `('f') OR` with `('t') OR`, the query completes quickly, and the cost goes down (back to 6283.94..10190.09).

Why would adding that `('f') OR` clause damage this query's performance so much?

Edit:
Here's the full EXPLAIN (VERBOSE) for the query with `('f') OR`

```
 Gather  (cost=1000.29..109033834.49 rows=32952 width=4)
   Output: categories.id
   Workers Planned: 1
   ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using categories_pkey on public.categories  (cost=0.29..109029539.29 rows=19384 width=4)
         Output: categories.id
         Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..5295.43 rows=131762 width=4)
                 Output: category_groups.category_id
                 ->  Seq Scan on public.category_groups  (cost=0.00..4121.62 rows=131762 width=4)
                       Output: category_groups.category_id
```

And here's the full explain for the query without `('f') OR`:

```
 Hash Anti Join  (cost=6283.94..10190.09 rows=1131 width=4)
   Output: categories.id
   Hash Cond: (categories.id = category_groups.category_id)
   ->  Index Only Scan using categories_pkey on public.categories  (cost=0.29..2213.44 rows=65903 width=4)
         Output: categories.id
   ->  Hash  (cost=4121.62..4121.62 rows=131762 width=4)
         Output: category_groups.category_id
         ->  Seq Scan on public.category_groups  (cost=0.00..4121.62 rows=131762 width=4)
               Output: category_groups.category_id
```

Comment: is `category_groups.category_id` nullable?

Comment: What's the intention behind writing `where false or ...`? But in general, `OR` conditions are hard to optimize (for any DBMS, not just Postgre**s**)

Comment: category_groups.category_id is not nullable. @SalmanA

Comment: Not sure what the intention is behind writing `where false or ...`, I think the SQL query is being automatically generated by the Ruby code which runs the query. Because the software that runs this query is 3rd party (so I don't actually own that code), it's difficult to change. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Can we see the full explain, please? What is the purpose of the `('f' )` in the query?

Comment: @Schwern ok, just added the full explains to the post.

Comment: @BrianK I'm surprised it's that slow with only 32952 rows. Have you [analyzed the tables](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/optimize-and-improve-postgresql-performance-with-vacuum-analyze-and-reindex-885239781.html)? Note that `where 'f' or X` is just `X`. [`'f'`, in boolean context, is `false`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html); the `f` does nothing but confuse the optimizer.

Comment: Ok sounds good, I'm analyzing and vacuuming the tables now, so hopefully that'll make things move faster. I'll let you know how it goes @Schwern

Comment: Please use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) to get both the plan and the results from this plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FALSE OR` prevents PostgreSQL from optimizing your `NOT IN` condition to an anti-join. The reason is that the PostgreSQL optimizer doesn't think hard enough for that. However, since it is easy to rewrite the query to do better (simple remove the `FALSE OR`), there is little reason to make the optimizer smarter. A smart optimizer is slow, and the gain of optimizing an ill-written query better does not outweigh the price that everyone would have to pay.